# tmux error for send-keys (trying to interact with xclip)

Tags: tmux

When I insert the following line in my tmux.conf

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -i -f -selection primary | xclip -i -selection clipboard"
```

> usage: send-keys [-lRM] [-t target-pane] key ...

Please help me understand what is happening. I am running tmux 2.1. I got the command [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/tmux-in-practice-integration-with-system-clipboard-bcd72c62ff7b) but they state nothing about the version.

Comment: Evidently your version of send-keys does not have a -X option, only the I R and M options listed in the output.

Comment: You are correct. This was only added later. After upgrading to 2.6, everything works correctly. Please, post it as an answer, so we can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you got is a description of the available options for `send-key` on your system:

> usage: send-keys [-lRM] [-t target-pane] key

So the available options are -I -R -M and -t, plus the mandatory `key` parameter. However, the command you tried to run had the option `-X copy-pipe-and-cancel`. So the message is trying to tell you that it doesn't know what this option means.

The most likely explanation is that the tutorial you found is based on a newer version of the program, where the -X option has been added.